# How to dynamically add whitespace in element's text?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to insert whitespace in DOM element.

For instance, I want to change this

```
<a></a>
```

to this

```
<a> </a>
```

If I manually add `&nbsp` to DOM element, then it renders `&nbsp` as a whitespace. But when I want to add this dynamically, I use `innerText`,

```
 a_element.innertText = "&nbsp"
```

and as result it doesn't convert `&nbsp` to whitespace and renders it as a text (`<a>&nbsp</a>`). How can I fix this?

Comment: you have to write `&nbsp;` instead of `&nbsp`

Comment: what's wrong with a_element.innerText = " " ?

Comment: @DaHaKa, I tried both with the same result

Comment: .innerHTML is what you need?

Comment: @DaHaKa you should make that an answer. It may be trivial but it probalbly is exactly what OP is looking for

Comment: @Sanchit, yes, thank you! It doesn't work with innerText but works with innerHTML. (however i don't see any difference between `&nbsp` and `&nbsp;`, probably because of the browser though)

Comment: `.innerText` takes any text literally. It does not parse HTML. If you want to use an HTML entity, you have to use `.innerHTML` as already said.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `.innerHTML` as you need to edit the HTML of that particular link.

```
a_element.innerHTML = "&nbsp;"
```

Comment: As a precaution, @Jukkas answer below is safer.  innerHTML is an attack vector.  If a user-supplied string is ever put into innerHTML, they can inject a script tag and do anything they want.

Answer (score 12):

HTML entity references are processed only in HTML parsing. In any case, it is best to put the character directly into the content. If you do not know how to type the no-break space in your authoring environment, you can use the `\xA0` or `\u00A0` escape in JavaScript:

```
a_element.innerText = "\u00A0";
```

BTW, the no-break space is not a [whitespace character](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#didx-white_space-1) by HTML specs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just copy the whitespace character you want and paste it into your javascript string. For instance, I had a `&emsp;` in my html; when I loaded the page, I copied that space and pasted it into a string in my javascript:

```
var myString = "Here is &emsp; --> <--";
```

Note that it looks like a regular space on here, but it renders into the original whitespace copied.